# Passing Parameters to a Named Command where command text contains IN

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How do I pass paramter values for a command where SQL Text contains IN.
i.e. My command SQL text is something like `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID IN (1,2,3)`.

There are plenty of examples like [MSDN has](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675788%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) but coudn't find one to pass values for IN. Tried taking a variable and set values as a single string but SQL wont work that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)

Comment: you mean passing values in a PreparedStatement or what ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a UDF which converts a (for example) csv string into a table of values.
Then, your query can be some thing like:

select * 
from yourTable
where yourField IN ( select yourColumn from dbo.yourUDF(yourCSV) )

Comment: Yes. This option was always there. I was just wondering if there is any I can omit this exercise as I dont wanted to modify the coming SQL except passing paramters and system replacing with their values.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is there's no good way to do this.

If you're indeed only working with a list of numeric values, you probably don't need to use parameters as this feature is mainly designed to prevent SQL injection attacks.  However, if you have an array of `int`s, and use that to build your query, you're safe.

The only other way I can think of would be to add one parameter per item.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID IN (@p1, @p2, @p3)
```

Then, loop through your array in C# and create a parameter for each item.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked many, many times. Two ways spring to mind:

If you have SQL2008, you can pass a "[table value parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)" *(tvp)*, where your table parameter has the values for your "in" clause, then have a "where" clause that checks values are "in (select *whatever* from tvp)".

If you do not have SQL2008, you can use a "common table expression" *(cte)*, such as...

```
declare @t table (xyz varchar(100))
insert into @t values ('hello')
insert into @t values ('there')
insert into @t values ('world')
insert into @t values ('10')
insert into @t values ('20')
insert into @t values ('30')

declare @a as varchar(120)
set @a = 'hello,10,30'

;with cte as
(
    select cast(null as varchar(max)) as 'v', 1 as s, charindex(',' , @a, 0) as e
union all
    select cast(substring(@a, s, e-s) as varchar(max)), e+1, charindex(',' , @a + ',', e+1)
    from cte where e!=0
)
select *
from @t
where (xyz in (select v from cte where v is not null))
```

In this example *(above)*, the string @a is the comma separated list of values you want for your "in" clause, and the *(recursive)* cte just strips out the values, one by one. Of course, this is just a quick example and would probably need checks for empty strings, successive commas,  and the like.

Of course, the usual caveats apply with regard to using SQL to *(effectively)* do string manipulation.

Regards,
Ross